# Question regarding javascript call resultion on function objects

Tags: javascript

I am a little bit confused regarding the way in which functions are actually called in javascript. Let's suppose we have the following sample code.

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log("hello world");
}
foo();
```

First, we create a function object which is referenced by foo, and then we invoke it. I went through the documentation which says that internally `foo()` actually invokes `call()` on the function object. This also makes sense, because, I can replace `foo()` with `foo.call()` and nothing changes for the example above.

However, let's suppose I wanted to create a function object in the following way:

```
class Function1 extends Function {
    call() {
        console.log("hello wold");
    }
}
const foo = new Function1();
foo.call();
```

When using `foo.call()`, the correct method is invoked. However, when I try to invoke `foo()`, I was hoping that the `call` method from `Function1` would be invoked which is not the case. I guess I am thinking in the wrong direction here. I just assumed that `foo.call()` and `foo()` would be equivalent when executed on function objects which does not seem to be the case. Could somebody give me a hint on how the call resolution actually works.

Comment: It looks like you're just shadowing `Function.prototype.call`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, the engine invokes `[[Call]]` (and not `call`), which is an internal method, not available in your code. If you want to intercept `[[Call]]`, the only way is to create a `Proxy` with an `apply` hook:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log('foo')
}

foo = new Proxy(foo, {
    apply(target) {
        console.log('foo called!')
        target()
    }
});

foo()
```